# Proxying Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler from Clojure

Tags: swing, exception, clojure, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to implement a "complete" uncaught exception handler, allowing to *also* catch EDT exceptions in Clojure.

I'm trying to implement the class from the accepted answer (with 15+ upvotes) from here:

[How can i catch Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448523/how-can-i-catch-event-dispatch-thread-edt-exceptions)

Here's the part that I'd like to port to Clojure:

```
public static class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    public void handle(Throwable thrown) {
      // for EDT exceptions
      handleException(Thread.currentThread().getName(), thrown);
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable thrown) {
      // for other uncaught exceptions
      handleException(thread.getName(), thrown);
    }

    protected void handleException(String tname, Throwable thrown) {
      System.err.println("Exception on " + tname);
      thrown.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());
    System.setProperty("sun.awt.exception.handler",
                       ExceptionHandler.class.getName());
```

However I'm stuck.  The `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is a public interface defined inside Thread and I can't seem to proxy it from Clojure.

I don't know what to import nor how to implement this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm having exceptions that I can seem to diagnose because they're "lost" somewhere in the EDT (and the EDT is automatically fixed / restarted).

Answer (score 1):

Use `reify` to implement `Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler`. Inner classes and interfaces from Java are named as  the class file.

```
(def h (reify Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler    
  (uncaughtException [this t e] 
    (println t ": " e))))
```

See: [Implementing Java generic interface in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999252/implementing-java-generic-interface-in-clojure)